# Quotient of a derived Artin stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

Let $X$ be a derived Artin stack and $G$ be a reductive group acting on $X$.

Does the quotient $X/G$ always exist in the category of derived Artin stacks?

Please provide a reference in case it is true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is yes, but I'm not the best person to provide a reference.

Comment: This is almost by definition. The case where $G$ acts trivially on the base is clear. To see that $X/G$ is an Artin stack, one observes that the induced map $X/G\to BG=*/G$ is representable (if we pullback along the universal $G$-torsor we get back $X$).